# Phpmyadmin not working after installing new version of Xubuntu 19.10

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

After updating to a new version of Xubuntu 19.10, I am getting an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php on line 70

when trying to connect to phpmyadmin. It works fine when I switch to php7.3 but I get this error message when using php5.6.

I need to  use php5.6 for my older projects.

I tried to reinstall apache2, php and phpmyadmin. Nothing seemed to work.

[image: This is the complete error message.]

Comment: I would suggest that you use our PPA
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515#issuecomment-548521407

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa

Comment: not working for us, php 5.6 ubuntu 19.04, /phpmyadmin shows empty page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which phpMyAdmin version you're using or from where you've acquired it, but the description makes it clear that you've encountered a version compatibility problem. You are trying to use a phpMyAdmin version that is not compatible with the PHP version you're running. I suggest running phpMyAdmin 4.9.x, which is currently in [long-term security support phase](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/#support) (where it gets important security fixes, but is no longer getting day-to-day bugfixes). Version 4.9.x supports PHP version 5.6 no problem.

As Williams suggests, you can use the phpMyAdmin repository (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa`) to keep up to date.